# How to use critical section

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, critical-section

Hello I would like to write a program with 2 concurrent threads. First thread writes to the array letter 'A' and second one writes 'B'. My question is how to use critical section to gain result with alternately array with only letter A and with only letter B ? Here is my code, but it is not work properly. What is wrong with it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#define SIZE_TAB 200

volatile char program[SIZE_TAB];
CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;
DWORD WINAPI aa(void *v);
DWORD WINAPI bb(void *v);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
InitializeCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

HANDLE thread_a = CreateThread(NULL, 0, aa, 0, 0, 0);
HANDLE thread_b = CreateThread(NULL, 0, bb, 0, 0, 0);

while (1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE_TAB; i++)
        printf("%c", program[i]);
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("\n\n");
}

DeleteCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

CloseHandle(thread_a);
CloseHandle(thread_b);
return 0;
}


 DWORD WINAPI aa(void *v)
 {

    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_TAB; i++)
    {
        program[i] = 'A';
        for (int j = 0; j<8000; j++);
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

   }

   DWORD WINAPI bb(void *v)
   {

    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE_TAB; i++)
    {
        program[i] = 'B';
        for (int j = 0; j<8000; j++);
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
   }
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is wrong with it? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I think it should shows alternately: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    new line:                   BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Comment: I know this just an exercise, but this is an antithetical to something you should want to do with threads.  If you want specific sequential behaviour, then you don't need threads.

Comment: you can not call `DeleteCriticalSection` until it possible in use

Comment: Critical sections provide mutual exclusion. They don't provider order or fairness guarantees. Your code behaves as expected. Your expectations are unfounded. If you want sequential output, don't use threads.

Comment: You are printing a character at a time on your main thread without any kind of synchronization. Sleep(1000) gives ample time for both threads to finish - even with the 8000 iteration empty loop. What will probably happen is, the main loop will print a couple of garbage characters, one of the threads will enter the critical section, and quickly fill the buffer and exit and the other one will then finish. So your first line will be something like xxxBBAAAAAAAA, and every subsequent line with be AAs.

Answer (score 5):

Critical section is a way of protecting data in a multi-threaded program. Once one thread enters a critical section, another thread cannot enter that same critical section until the first thread leaves it.

You have three threads in play here: the main thread, aa and bb. You have ensured that threads aa and bb cannot access the same data at the same time by protecting it with a critical section, but you left it open for the main thread to access it at any time (in the main loop where you print out the array). The main thread is not modifying it, but it is accessing it, so it will print out whatever it finds in the array at the time: the first thread that entered the critical section may have finished modifying the data or it may have not. Furthermore, you have surrounded the entire function body with a critical section in both aa and bb, which means that the first thread to enter it will have fully run through the loop before the other thread gets the chance.

Comment: Thank You for reply. So in main thread should I add EnterCriticalSection before while or dont use critical section in bb or aa?

Comment: If you surround the for loop in the main thread (not the while loop) with the critical section it will probably first print all A's (or B's depending on which thread entered the critical section first) and then the other letter but it all depends on timing. Is that what you want?

Comment: As others have said if you want sequential behavior there is no need to use threads.

Comment: I made it and it's not work properly it shows all the time letter 'B. Yea I want sequential behavior but with threads and critical section if it is possible.

Comment: OK, if you add the critical section in the main thread for loop (and remove the sleep) and add while loops in your threads (with the critical section surrounding the for loop just like in the main thread) you should start to see it alternate. But you may want to ask another question where you explain why you want sequential behavior with threads, there is probably a better solution than this.

Comment: I believe it is not correct for `main` to access the data while `aa` or `bb` can modify it